# 4.2.2 - 4.4.2 Service Error

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

4.2.2 I am doing operations background with the device in my actions do the service I have Summer Time and the statement printing'm intervals according to the result. (Seems I Service in Running Applications in Practice and 1 Service 1 as a process.)

---

4.4.2 If the service is running, but the timer is turned off and program service and background processes do not work (applications running in the application process 1 Service 0) as ticking ... Notice, etc. I can not process